# Confused over the shape of Feature Map

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Taking for example a simple $(5,5,3)$ image where height=5, width=5, channels=3. If we define 2 filters of shape $(3,3,3)$ where each filter is of height=3, width=3, channels=3. We convolve these 2 filters on the input image with Stride=1, and no padding, then our output is $(3,3,2)$. Is this output a feature map? If so, then is $(3,3,2)$ an image? I would think it is actually 2 images?

Comment: That's right, by applying one filter to an image, we obtain a feature map. In this case we apply 2 filters $\to$ we obtain 2 feature maps, each one of size $(3,3)$. Intuitively we can think that these are two new images (two different transformations of the original one).